# How can I use Node.js library from within an Android native app?

Tags: android, node.js

I have to use an npm library from an Android native app. The app is a CAD-compatible app which should export to DXF or DWG, and since DXF libraries on Java are either proprietary or outdated, I have to rely on options on other languages. (Sure, it might fall into an XY problem, but using other languages will also stumble into this kind of problem-like Python or C#.)

How do I call the library from inside? Compared to similar questions and existing solutions,

- [This solution by Janea Systems](https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile/getting-started-android) is the closest to what I want to achieve, but it seems to be outdated.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632649/running-node-js-on-android), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111377/run-nodejs-server-in-android) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145308/nodejs-on-ios-android?rq=1) all present outdated solutions or solutions which has to be installed by the **user**. I want the libraries bundled by the **vendor** as part of the app.
- Making a React Native app would be the most flawless way, but it is not feasible at this stage. I already implemented the core functionality of the app except for the export feature at this stage.

Comment: Have you looked at [ADXF](https://jsevy.com/wordpress/index.php/java-and-android/android-apps-and-libraries/android-adxf-library/) and [JDXF](https://jsevy.com/wordpress/index.php/java-and-android/jdxf-java-dxf-library/)?

Comment: @RickyMo JDXF doesn't support Android (because they use classes explicit to Oracle Java), while ADXF does not support ONE header (metric) that is required for my app.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this document in the React Native official website](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps), you can switch an existing app to a React Native app simply by adding a `ReactRootView` somewhere in the application hierarchy and adding corresponding JavaScript components. That means an activity requiring a Node functionality as in my scenario can easily be delegated onto an activity with a `ReactRootView` as its root view. Your entire app **don't** have to be React-capable if you don't aim for multiplatform capability.

You are likely to stumble into issues, however. [Obviously you have to setup a React Native development environment first](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), you have to specify your package name on the manifest on the contrary of what Android Studio tells you to (if you find how not to, please tell me), and `android.permission.INTERNET` and `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` (for debug builds) have to be given to the application.

In my scenario, I had to forward data to the Node library and save the result as a file. I launched the activity in the one-shot manner and returned to the native app from within the JavaScript code.